# Angular doesn't recognize directives

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I have a problem when I try to use the angular´s directives, for instance when I want to use *ngIf the project does not recognize the directive and throws the following error

[image]

In addition to some time here it began to show this other error that I really don't know what it is

[image]

This is the main module

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of text, just copy and paste it here.

Comment: Looks like you’re missing CommonModule?

Comment: The error give you VisualStudio. I suggest install some of the multiples Angular extensions. I like the [Angular Essentials' John Papa](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.angular-essentials) but there're another ones